# Filling Multiple Images in Matlab

Tags: image, matlab, fill

I have the following code to import multiple images from one directory into a struct in Matlab, here is an example of the images.

[image]

```
myPath= 'E:\conduit_stl(smooth contour)\Collagen Contour Slices\'; %'
fileNames = dir(fullfile(myPath, '*.tif'));
C = cell(length(fileNames), 1);

for k = 1:length(fileNames)
    filename = fileNames(k).name;
    C{k} = imread(filename);
    se = strel('disk', 2, 0);
    C = imclose(C, se);
    filled = imfill(C,'holes');
end
```

Though now I would like to perform a fill on all the images, later finding the centroids. However, when attempting this, an error stating: "Expected input number 1, I1 or BW1, to be one of these types: double, ... etc" I tried converting the images into double precision, though that just resulted in: "Conversion to double from cell is not possible."

This is most likely due to the structure type, the images are 'housed' in, but I have no idea concerning that.

Help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `C` is not a structure but rather a cell array (as you initialized it). That would be more efficient to store your images in a "regular" array. Also, since you are using the same structuring element for all images you can take it out of the loop and define it only once.

Comment: Do you mean to also change the curly brackets to regular brackets? If I do that, I get this error: "Conversion to cell from uint8 is not possible."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So to elaborate on my previous comments, here are a few things to change with your code:

`C` is not a structure but a cell array. The content of a cell array is access with {curly brackets}. If all your images are the same size, then it is more efficient to store them into a numeric array instead of a cell array. Since they seem to be logical images, your array would have 3 dimensions:

```
[height, width, numberofimages]
```

You could therefore start your code with:

```
myPath= 'E:\conduit_stl(smooth contour)\Collagen Contour Slices\'; %'
fileNames = dir(fullfile(myPath, '*.tif'));

%// if your images are of type uint8
C(height,width,length(fileNames)) = uint8(0);
C_filled = C; %// initialize new array to stored filled images
```

Also, since you are using the same structuring elements for your morphological operation on all the images, you can define it once outside the loop.

So your code could look like this:

```
se = strel('disk', 2, 0);
for k = 1:length(fileNames)

    C(:,:,k) = imread(fileNames(k).name);    
    C_filled(:,:,k) = imfill(imclose(C(:,:,k), se),'holes');

end
```

Comment: When I set my array dimensions, I get this error: Error: Unbalanced or unexpected parenthesis or bracket. for "C(256,256,3270(fileNames)) = uint8(0);"

Comment: why the 3270? You can leave `length(fileNames)`. Also just to make sure your images are greyscale uint8 right?

Comment: Ah, that might be the problem. They are binary, I imagine that's why I get "Conversion to cell from uint8 is not possible."

Comment: I am not sure what the problem is as I've checked and the images are already 8-bit.

Comment: what do you get when you type `size(imread(fileNames(1).name))`?

Comment: Size is given as: 256 256

Comment: mhh. So now what's the error? I'm a bit lost haha sorry.

Comment: My apologies, I had a previous variable in my workspace which was messing everything up. All  matters have bee resolved, thanks for your patience.

Comment: oh that's great then happy to help :)